# DCMTK Setting and reading the AE Source Tag

Tags: dcmtk

When exporting a DICOM file, I set these two tags in exactly the same way:

```
putAndInsertString(metaInfo, DCM_ImplementationVersionName, pDD->Imp_Version_Name);    
putAndInsertString(metaInfo, DCM_SourceApplicationEntityTitle, pDD->Source_AE_Title);
```

When receiving at the other end, I pull them out in the same way:

```
if (metaInfo->findAndGetOFString(DCM_ImplementationVersionName, tmpStr).good())      
{
    pDD->Imp_Version_Name = tmpStr.c_str();
}
else AddToLog("No Imp_Version_Name in metaInfo");
    
if (metaInfo->findAndGetOFString(DCM_SourceApplicationEntityTitle, tmpStr).good())      
{
    pDD->Source_AE_Title = tmpStr.c_str();
}
else AddToLog("No Source AE Title in metaInfo");
```

The Imp_Version_Name tag is recieved fine, but the AE Title tag is not.  The returned error
info is:  theStatus = error, theCode = 2, and theText = Tag not found

So, the only difference is that the AE Title VR type is AE instead of some string type?
Should I use something other than 'findAndGetOFString' to pull it out?  But DCMTK doc says this should work for AE type...

I have also tried, and had exact same results when I instead use the tag
DCM_SendingApplicationEntityTitle

What is going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "When receiving at the other end"? Of course, the File Meta Information (meta header) is not transferred using the DICOM Storage Service.

Comment: Its not?  How does one get the sender's AE?  and Imp_Version_Name works for me.... ?

Comment: The DICOM Storage Service transfers DICOM Data Sets and not DICOM files, so the File Meta Information has to be created by the Storage SCP when storing the data to a DICOM file (see DICOM part 10 for details). The Source AE Title could be extracted from the network communication between Storage SCU and Storage SCP, e.g. DCMTK's storescp and dcmrecv tools do this.